# Create library without package dependency using Firebase Android SDK

Tags: android, design-patterns, firebase

Since we keep switching our backend depedencies (Previously parse, then backendless now firebase), I am trying to create a backend library for all my projects with adapters for specific backends and common interface to be used in the projects (Adapter Design pattern).

For example,

The backend library interface will have method,

```
save(User user)
```

and the adapters will have implementation to save the User in firebase or backendless, and I can easily switch

But the way the firebase sdk works, we need to have 'google-services.json' in our path with predefined 'package name', otherwise we would get the following error in gradle build,

> Execution failed for task ':backend:processReleaseGoogleServices'. 
>   No matching client found for package name 'com.lib.backend'

The error is obvious, as the google-services.json would have the packagename of the specific project.

So now is there a way or a procedure I could follow, where my projects will not use the 'Firebase' classes directly and it works only through the 'backend' library.

Answer (score 1):

A simple combination of [Bridge pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) and [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)  should be enough. Create an interface in your app/library, create another library module which implement that interface using Firebase (with the plugin), and use DI in order to load your implementation. Whenever you want to change implementation, just replace this library module to some other implementation.

### Edit: an example

We'll create a project with 3 modules:

- Application module
- Interface module (for reference from two other modules)
- Firebase implementation of interface

You project should look like this:

[image]

Firebase module package name same as the app package name.

Next, we'll create the Firebase impl gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    provided project(':proxylib')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In our app module gradle build file, we'll need to include both modules:

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':firebaseproxy')
    compile project(':proxylib')
}
```

And we'll put our `google-services.json` file in the firebase module dir:

[image]

Code is simple. The interface looks something like this:

```
public interface BackendProxy {
    void save(String user);
}
```

And our Firebase implementation looks like:

```
public class BackendProxyImpl implements BackendProxy {
    @Override
    public void save(String message) {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        ...
        //save data to db
    }
}
```

**Note:** I haven't tried actually implementing the database part, but it seems like it is running the google play gradle task. While it seems ok to me, I would have expect the google-play task to use the applicationId property, which is not available in the library module. If something is build wrong because of this, you'll have to run the google-play gradle task from the app module.

Comment: The real problem mentioned here is the build process of Firebase SDK, which needs the 'google-servies.json' file in the same package

Comment: 1. My original intention was that It's possible to use the plugin + 'google-services.json' in a sub-module which the app is dependent on. I've done it, and can post the code/structure, if you don't know how to do it. 2. You can still put all Firebase related code in a sub-module, and have only the gradle script running in the app module.

Comment: Could you please post the code/structure?, mainly where will you have 'google-services.json' file and which gradle file will have the firebase dependencies?

Comment: Updated. See if it's making sense to you now.

Comment: As you mentioned,  
"Firebase module package name same as the app package name."
Are you very sure about this?, I keep getting this error and i dont think we can do this,

"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDevDebugResources'.
> Error: A library uses the same package as this project:"